# Modify a class dynamically during the run time (Send parameters to method and return) JAVA

Tags: java, performance, swing

im trying to modify a class when the program is debugging. But not just that, i want to create a method how receive a string a a parameter, and returns that string, i don't understand totally the code.

this is the method to modify a class when the program is debugging, and it works:

```
File sourceFile = new File("/Users/fpradines/Documents/AutoBot/src/main/java/Hello.java");
          JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
          StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(
              null, null, null);

          try {
            fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays
                  .asList(new File("/Users/fpradines/Documents/AutoBot/src/main/")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          // Compile the file
          boolean success = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null,
              fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(sourceFile)))
              .call();
          try {
            fileManager.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


          runIt();
```

Here is the runIt method and it works only when don't have to return anything and i didn't send a parameter:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static void runIt() {
    try {
      Class<?> params[] = {};
      Object paramsObj[] = {};
      Class<?> thisClass = Class.forName("Hello");
      Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();
      Method thisMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod("algo", params);
      thisMethod.invoke(iClass, paramsObj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The class that is being modified is this:

```
public class Hello {
public String algo(String value){   
    System.out.println("Hello worlds");
    value = "hello";
    return value;
    }
```

}

I want to send a string parameter to my Hello class,like i did, and then i want the class to return that value when i call the function runIt(); 
i don't know how to send a parameter and i don't know how to catch the return

i was thinking in something like this:`String value = thisMethod.invoke(iClass, paramsObj);`

but is not working

Pease any ideas are welcome, thanks!

Comment: When you say it is not working what do you mean, does it throw some error? generally invoke will return a  object you have to cast it.

Comment: i mean that i don't know how to send a parameter to the method algo(String) and i don't know how to get the return of that function, because this code is new for me and i don't understand it totally
i need a example code of what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works.

your params should have the list of types.

for eg if your method takes two arguments a String and a Integer params should be

```
Class<?> params[] = {Class.forName("java.lang.String"),Class.forName("java.lang.Integer")};
```

your paramsObj should be the actual array of objects that you want to send.

```
Object paramsObj[] = {"Testing", new Integer(1)};
```

In your case this below code should work

```
    Class<?> params[] = {Class.forName("java.lang.String")};
    Object paramsObj[] = {"Testing"};
    Class<?> thisClass = Class.forName("Hello");
    Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();
    Method thisMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod("algo", params);
    Object str= thisMethod.invoke(iClass, paramsObj);
    System.out.println(str);
```